# BSD getmicrotime() output to Excel Date

Tags: c, excel, bsd

What does C BSD getmicrotime() function returns?Does it returns epoch time in Unix? How to convert that to Excel Date Format?

Comment: Well, what did its documentation say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns void, however it sets the `timeval` pointer that you pass to it. Normally the microseconds which have elapsed since the Unix Epoch.

As to how to convert it to Excel Date, I'm unsure.

Answer (score 0):

To convert to Excel date time we need to do :

```
(getmicrotime() / 86400) + 25569
```

This will give the corresponding excel date at GMT